# Python Error unbound method?

Tags: python

If I try to run a command from https://github.com/ilovecode1/sandshell.py it gives me the error bellow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method runsingle() must be called with sandshell instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Thanks You!

Comment: Show us how you are trying to run the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, it is a convention of the language that instance methods are required to consume a special first argument (conventionally called `self`) that represents the actual instance object from which they will be called.

You can change your function definition to this:

```
def runsingle(self, command):
   ...
```

and then regular usage will work as expected, such as

```
ss = sandshell()
ss.runsingle(some_command)
```

because the special `self` argument is taken care of behind the scenes (you don't need to provide it explicitly when you call the function).

If instead you would like to run the command as a *static* method (meaning it has no dependency on either the class object or the instance object from which it is called) so that it is called as `sandshell.runsingle(some_command)` without first creating an instance of the `sandshell` class, then you can use the `staticmethod` decorator:

```
@staticmethod
def runsingle(command):
    ...
```

and so on for the other class functions as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do this:

```
import sandshell

instance = sandshell.sandshell()  # get an instance of the class
instance.runsingle("cd hi")       # call the method runsingle of the instance
```

You first need to have instance of class, then you can call function on that instance.

Comment: This won't work since the methods are defined without `self`. Either `self` needs to be added, or it needs to be made into a `classmethod` and the class argument needs to be added, or it needs to be made into a `staticmethod`.

Comment: @Mr.F ok but at the end he does not have instance. Hem

Comment: I'm just saying that if you left the code's original function definition as-is and the only change was to first make an instance and then try to run the function, it will not work (and will give the same error).

Comment: @Mr.F I understand, I did not try to run code. but point is same, he does not have instance.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried this before it did not work. But `self` does work well.